# How can I get UTC equivalents of Today_and_Now() and Today() in Perl?

Tags: perl, datetime

How can I get UTC equivalents of Today_and_Now() and Today() call results?
Can I convert them back to local time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using Today_and_Now() I assume that you're using [Date::Calc](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Date-Calc/). So, if you read the docs you will find that you can pass a parameter to both of those that indicates that gmtime() should be used as input rather than localtime(). Simply pass any true value to the these functions.

```
   my ($year,$month,$day) = Today(1);
   my ($year,$month, $day, $hours, $mins, $secs) = Today_and_Now(1);
```

Comment: Why didn't you link directly to Date::Calc http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Date::Calc or http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Date::Calc ?

Answer (score 2):

I've turned into more of a fan of DateTime each time I use it.

```
my $local_tz = DateTime::TimeZone->new( name=> 'local' );
my $now = DateTime->now( time_zone => $local_tz );

$now->set_time_zone('UTC');
say $now->hour();  ### UTC

$now->set_time_zone($local_tz);
say $now->hour();  ### Back to local time
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at "[Programmatic Time Usage With Perl](http://www.aota.net/Script_Installation_Tips/perltime.php4)". This will explain you the brief summary of tips for using time functions in Perl.

Other then this you can also have a look at some perl modules i.e. [Time::UTC::Now](http://search.cpan.org/~zefram/Time-UTC-Now-0.007/lib/Time/UTC/Now.pm) and [DateTime::TimeZone](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DateTime-TimeZone/lib/DateTime/TimeZone.pm)